# Why is it better to use a 64bit OS?

Tags: linux, 64bit, 32bit

Speed/Security? Why should we choose to use 64 bit instead of 32 bit?

Comment: Who told you that is is better? Both has advantages and disadvantages. It all depends on what you use your computer for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I install 32 or 64 bit?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26928/should-i-install-32-or-64-bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Main advantages amd64 over i386**

- 64-bit integer capability
- additional registers
- additional XMM (SSE) registers
- larger physical address space in legacy mode
- SSE/SSE2

for more details look at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD64) page.

**What about performance?**

Actually performance will grow up to 20-30% in general case. Its mainly due to intelligent compilers that can optimize even non-optimized code for new architecture (mainly due to SSE/SSE2 usage instead of FPU). 
PS. In 2009 phoronix made research about this issue. [Here it is](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_32_pae).

**Additional features**

In many tools now you can use arithmetic operations while it was too expensive in 32bit system. For example your `ifconfig`'s traffic counter won't reset after 4G level anymore itself (except reboot).

**Possible troubles**

The main problem is proprietary software. In case software developer spread their product only in binary for 32bit you may have a lot of problems. Sometimes it is possible to find workaround. And hopefully in the GNU/Linux world most of widely used software is open source.

Answer (score 4):

The main benefit to 64-bit systems is the increased memory address space which is limited to 4GB with 32-bit systems.

This question on the Superuser SE might be helpful: [32-bit vs. 64-bit systems](https://superuser.com/questions/56540/32-bit-vs-64-bit-systems).

Also, here's an informal exploration of [32-vs-64 bit OSes](http://lifehacker.com/5431284/the-lifehacker-guide-to-64+bit-vs-32+bit-operating-systems) on LifeHacker (though it focuses on Windows, much of it applies I think)

Comment: +1. As a *very* general rule of thumb, are probably better off running 64-bit if you have more than 3GB. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier. If you have less than 3GB you're probably better off with 32-bit.

Comment: @bahamat I always knew that with XP for instance I couldn't get past 3GB, but always a bit confused because of the stated 4GB limit. I know 2^32 = 4GB, is it the OSes that limits the space to 3GB?

Comment: as is often the case, "it depends". Mac OS X has the 3GB limit on 32-bit and Linux must be compiled with PAE enabled to avoid it. Reasons pro and con 64-bit have mostly been mentioned already so I just wanted to point out a quick and easy "If unsure, do this".

Comment: @bahamat Thanks .. I'm certainly happy to be able to make use of all the 8GB RAM on my 64-bit system now :)

Comment: @Levon OSes reserve a portion of the address space for internal use. Traditionally in 32-bit systems, they reserved the upper 2 GiB of the 32-bit address space, then the upper 1 GiB and some even the upper 512 MiB only. Some reservation is however required for technical reasons, so even when the OS uses 32-bit linear addressing you don't get to use the full 32-bit address space for your own (applications') benefit. Similar to how the good ol' IBM PC and MS-DOS reserved the upper 384 KiB of the 8086's 1 MiB address space for various system uses, leaving applications to run in the lower 640 KiB.

Answer (score 0):

Some 64-bit programs, such as encoders, decoders and encryption software, can benefit greatly from 64-bit registers, while the performance of other programs, such as 3D graphics-oriented ones, remains unaffected when switching from a 32-bit to a 64-bit environment.